# getJSON cross domain request vs. search variable

Tags: jquery, json, variables, cross-domain

I'm trying to get the field values ​​using as JSON query variables, but with variable nothing works.
I try this:

```
var a='ptmedia';var c='2.90';var v='ver';var n='name';
$.getJSON('http://example.com?callback=?',function(d){
    var q=d.app.a.v;
    if(c<q){alert('Some text'+d.n+'some text');}
});
```

but i did something wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
d.app[a][v]
```

And:

```
d[n]
```